# cannot import name 'is_torch_greater_or_equal_than_1_13' from 'transformers.pytorch_utils'

Tags: pytorch

How to resolve this issue?

```
 from transformers import Trainer
 trainer = Trainer(model_init = model_init,
              args = training_args,
              data_collator = data_collator,
              compute_metrics = compute_metrics,
              train_dataset = panx_de_encoded["train"],
              eval_dataset = panx_de_encoded["validation"],
              tokenizer = xlmr_tokenizer)
 trainer.train()
```

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.trainer because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'is_torch_greater_or_equal_than_1_13' from 'transformers.pytorch_utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pytorch_utils.py)

I tried to upgrade torch, but doesn't help.